# for loop iteration fails in apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a scenario to display Roles(Authorized, Complaint and Cable Assessment) as shown in the second image below:

Every Contact has Authorized and Complaint as Roles. If there is no 'Cable assesment' role then add it as the 3rd row with 'Unknown' values as shown in the code.

If there is already cable assessment then no need to add again.

Here is my apex code:

```
//Loop through Contacts add to new Contact list

        anewContact = new List<Contact> ();

        For (Contact aContact : aContacts) {

        if(aContacts.size() == 2){
            anewContact.add(new Contact(id = aContact.id, FirstName = aContact.FirstName, LastName = aContact.LastName));

            //add cable assessment if we dont have

            anewContact.add(new Contact(id = aContact.id, REL_VS_Contact_Role__c='Cable Assessment Contact', FirstName = 'Unknown', LastName = 'Unknown'));
}
else
anewContact.add(new Contact(id = aContact.id, FirstName = aContact.FirstName, LastName = aContact.LastName));
}
```

[image: I wanted to display Authorized, Complaint and Cable assessment contact]

Comment: i am not clear what the issue is here. what is going *wrong*?

Answer (score 1):

This is basic programming logic.

Because you have `if(aContacts.size() == 2)` in the for loop, every time you have 2 roles you will *always* have 2 Cable Assessments.

You haven't provided enough information about the rest of the your code here for us to really help, but you're probably going to have to add the Cable Assessments outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The size of aContacts isn't going to change in this code so if it's equal to 2 it's always going to go into the if == 2 condition and it's going to add the unknown contact for each contact.